# Can someone explain, in steps, how this problem is simplified into the provided result?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How is this problem:
$$
\frac{-25+30\ln(x)}{2x^4} = 0
$$
simplified into this:
$$
-5 + 6\ln(x) = 0?
$$

Comment: **Hints:** Only the numerator can be zero. Also, divide out a $5$.

Comment: @Moo How is that a hint??? That's a full blown solution, and ought to be posted as such

Comment: I appreciate the hint. However, I was looking for a step-by-step solution like the one posted by @Jaideep Khare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{-25+30\ln(x)}{2x^4} =\frac{5(-5+6\ln(x))}{2x^4}= 0$$

$$\frac{5(-5+6\ln(x))}{2x^4} \times \frac{2x^4}{5} = 0 \times \frac{2x^4}{5}$$

$$\implies -5+6\ln(x)= 0$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{-25+30\ln(x)}{2x^4}=0\hspace{27mm}|\times2x^4$

$-25+30\ln(x)=0\times2x^4$

$-25+30\ln(x)=0$

$5\times[-5+6\ln(x)]=0\hspace{13mm}|\div5$

$-5+6\ln(x)=\frac{0}{5}$

$-5+6\ln(x)=0$